# How to handle on notification at a time among concurrent notifications received

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, notification-listener

we have a server sends notification to an App, the notifcations received by the App is handled using NotificationListenerService. The App will be able to receive the notifications when 
it is connected WiFi.

Now, when the App is connected to WiFi it receives and handles the notifications normally and every thing seems fine. But when the server sends notifications"more than one notification" while the WiFi of the App 
is disabled, it seems that the App assemble or stack these notifications and once the WiFi is enabled, all notifications will be executed concurrently and this is something we want 
get rid of. In other words, assuming now that, WiFi of the App is disabled, and the server sent 3 notifications, when the user turns the WiFi of the App on again, all the three
notification will call the following method

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)
```

the code posted below shows how the methods of 'NotificationListenerService' are coded.

To solve this issue, I synchronized the lines that starts new thread as shown in the code, but still this did not solve the issue.

Please let t mek now how to handle only one notification even if i am receiving several/stream of concurrent notifications

**Note**:  I mean by handling the notification in our App is the sound to be played indication/signaling arrival of a notification.

**code**:

```
public class NLSNotificationTone extends NotificationListenerService {

private final static String TAG = NLSNotificationTone.class.getSimpleName();
private final static int sDurationOfRingTone = 7; //60 seconds
private boolean mNotificationRemoved;
private static boolean TONE_IS_PLAYING = false;

private Handler handler = null;
private Ringtone mRingTone;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Toast.makeText(this, "NLSNotificationTone->onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (String) msg.obj, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
}


@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
    Log.w(TAG, "onNotificationPosted");

    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.obj = "onNotificationPosted";
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    mNotificationRemoved = false;

    /*when a notification is recieved, a tone should be played, and if-statement below, is, as long as there is a notification received while a sound is playing which belongs to 
    a previous notification, then do not play sound again. This to prevent two or more notifications' sound to interchange/mix-up*/
    synchronized (this) {
        if (!NLSNotificationTone.TONE_IS_PLAYING)
            new ThreadPlayTone(this, NLSNotificationTone.sDurationOfRingTone).start();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
    Log.w(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved");

    NLSNotificationTone.TONE_IS_PLAYING = false;
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
    msg.obj = "onNotificationRemoved";
    handler.sendMessage(msg);
}

private class ThreadPlayTone extends Thread {

    private Context mContext = null;
    private int mDurationOfRingTone;
    private Ringtone mRingTone = null;

    public ThreadPlayTone(Context context, int duration) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDurationOfRingTone = duration;

        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        this.mRingTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, notification);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();

        Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
        msg.obj = "ThreadPlayTone started";
        handler.sendMessage(msg);

        int initTime = (int) TimeUtils.getTSSec();
        while (!mNotificationRemoved && (TimeUtils.getTSSec() - initTime) < this.mDurationOfRingTone) {
            Log.w(TAG, "ThreadPlayTone->run->while-loop: " + + ((TimeUtils.getTSSec() - initTime) + 1) + "sec");

            /**this method seems asynchronous, it returns immediately*/
            this.mRingTone.play();
            /*we call this to make sure that ringtone is finished, as long as it is playing, then do nothing, or in other words, wait till
            * it finishes*/
            while(this.mRingTone.isPlaying()) {}
        }

        NLSNotificationTone.TONE_IS_PLAYING = true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to show only one notification instead of three separate notification in your case I'm I right?

Comment: @jeevanvenugopal yes exactly..if the server sent more than  notification while the wifi of the App is disabled, when the wifi is On again, the NotificationListenerService should handle one notifiction only,..Wht I mean by handling the notification in our App is the sound to be played indication/signaling arrival of a notification.

Comment: Have you tried synchronized keyword with the onNotificationPosted method or instead of creating Thread subclass, create AsynTask class subclass because it executes threads in serial (or use ThreadPoolExecutor).

Comment: You can keep one boolean flag and can flip it to true on network arrives(BroadcastReceiver or NetworkRequest) and then back to false in the onNotificationPosted

Comment: @ShailendraYadav no i have not tried actually. but do you think it would make difference?! i do not think so because it seems that on NotificationPosted will be called once for each notification i.e: for each received notification onNotificationReceived will be called. To substantiate my point, if you checked the code I posted, the flag 'NLSNotificationTone.TONE_IS_PLAYING' in onNotificationPosted will be true if and only if the sound of earlier notification ended

Comment: @user2121 What about the second comment, you can give a try.